# If I pay for a software, do I have the rights to access its source code?

Tags: united-states, copyright, software

In other words, can I reverse engineer the software that I paid for? I feel like since I spent money, I should be able to know what the software is actually doing and does it have any hidden malware or spyware. I will NOT resell or republish the software.

Comment: Your argument is really unconvincing. By your logic, you should be able to know the exact Coca Cola recipe if you buy a coke.

Comment: @Roland Except you can with coca cola (as long as you have the tools to reverse engineer the recipe, perhaps a mass spec machine).  The difference here is that source code is creative expression and protected by copyright, the recipe for coke is not.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184874/is-ken-thompsons-compiler-hack-still-a-threat seems relevant here...

Answer (score 1):

### Not necessarily

By buying a software package such as MS Office, Adobe Photoshop, Clip Studio Paint, and many others, you usually don't acquire the software itself, you buy a **license**. That license comes with the right to use the programs attached to it, but does not transfer any ownership of or access to the source code.

By accessing a free "open source" software package such as Open Office or GIMP you usually gain a license to install the software, use it and at the same time get access and usage/modification rights to the source code. That is part of the Open Source idea.

**Some** software does come with (part of) its sourcecode bundled, with the specific intent to allow modification. Those software packages include game engines, such as Unity.

And then there is the option to approach the programmer and buy the software. Read your contract in those cases - Some contracts like this do **not** come with the source code or right to modify the software, others do.

### Copyright exceptions?

There is a right to decompile software for *research*, but it might be a stretch that 'looking for hidden malware' requires the source code, when reading out processing operations done can be enough.

Answer (score 0):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

> If I pay for a software, do I have the rights to access its source code?

> In other words, can I reverse engineer the software that I paid for?

Those are two very different questions.

> If I pay for a software, do I have the rights to access its source code?

Generally not. When you pay for a software *license*, you have the rights to do anything the rights holder grants you in the license. *Usually*, that does not include access to the source code.

However, some licenses *do* give you the right to access the source code. For example, if you receive software under the terms of the [*General Public License*](https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0), then you have the right to access the source code. More than that, you have the right to create your own version and re-distribute it, including selling it for profit, as long as you yourself abide by the terms of the GPL.

Even commercial vendors sometimes make proprietary software available under licenses which include source code. For example, Microsoft offers the source code of Windows both under an academic license to academic researchers in the field of operating systems (e.g., the developers of the [*Xen* Type-1 Hypervisor](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Xen) got access to the source code of Windows XP and ported it to run on Xen) and under a government license to government agencies tasked with information security (e.g., the [*National Security Agency*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Security_Agency) and [*National Institute of Standards and Technology*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institute_of_Standards_and_Technology) in the United States, the [*Bundesamt für Sicherheit in der Informationstechnik* (Federal Office for Information Security)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Office_for_Information_Security) in Germany, or the [*Government Communications Headquarters*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/GCHQ) in the United Kingdom).

But this is unusual. The overwhelming majority of commercially-available proprietary software licenses will not allow access to the source code.

> In other words, can I reverse engineer the software that I paid for?

That is a different question. Reverse engineering neither requires nor gives access to the source code.

Reverse engineering *of trade secrets* is generally allowed in Germany as of 2019.

Before 2019, gaining knowledge of trade secrets through reverse engineering was *only* allowed for purposes of interoperability. I.e., **IFF** you were developing a product which requires interoperating with another product **AND** the manufacturer of that product refused to make interoperability documentation available to you under reasonable terms, **THEN AND ONLY THEN** were you allowed to reverse engineer the product to gain knowledge of trade secrets. Note that charging a one-time and/or per-unit license fee was *not* considered unreasonable.

Since 2019, gaining knowledge of trade secrets through reverse engineering is generally allowed by §3,I (2) of the [*Gesetz zum Schutz von Geschäftsgeheimnissen (GeschGehG)* (Law on the Protection of Trade Secrets)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_on_the_Protection_of_Trade_Secrets).

If a product has been made available to the general public, it can be reverse engineered. If a product has not been made available to the public but only to specific persons (for example, development partners), reverse engineering can be contractually disallowed.

However, note that this *only* applies to *trade secrets*. Other forms of intellectual property such as copyright, patents, trademarks, and others, are unaffected.

On the other hand, you are generally allowed to check everything you buy, including software, to make sure it is safe to use, and this includes reverse engineering it. So, it is allowed to reverse engineer software to ensure it does not contain malware, does not damage your hardware, etc. This also applies to fixing defects.

It is also allowed to perform reverse engineering for educational and research purposes.

> I feel like since I spent money, I should be able to know what the software is actually doing and does it have any hidden malware or spyware.

You do have this right, but it does not give you access to the source code. It only allows you to reverse engineer the software.

Answer (score -1):

It depends entirely on the software. Much open source software is published under a license that requires the source to be made available to any licensee of the software. The Linux operating system is an example of this sort of software.

Other software is "closed source": you are entitled to a copy of the binaries for the software, but have no right to the source. Microsoft Word and Adobe Photoshop are examples of this sort of software. The license may also explicitly forbid reverse engineering, but the validity of this clause may depend on the polity where the software is used. In the US such a clause is generally valid.